# How to do caseinsensitive in dataTable() using fnFilter() in jquery?

Tags: jquery, datatables, case-insensitive, fnfilter

Trying to search table irrespective of the case using `fnFilter` for `dataTable()`

```
$('#search-users').on('keyup',function(){
if(tblActive){
             tableActive._fnFilter($(this).val());
             tableActive._fnDraw();
            }
         });
```

Unable to get a caseinsensitive data filter. I want my table to search for values irrespective of their case. I tried giving

```
 tableActive._fnFilter($(this).val(),true);
```

But unable to search caseinsensitive data.

Comment: https://datatables.net/reference/option/search.caseInsensitive

Comment: "search": {
    "caseInsensitive": false} i tried using this..but its not working

Comment: First of all: What version of dataTables are you using ..?

Comment: 1.10.4 jquery.dataTables.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.10.4 jquery.dataTables.js

Then use the API! dataTables filtering *is* case insensitive by default. Either :

```
var tableActive = $(<selector>).DataTable({ .. });

$('#search-users').on('keyup', function() {
  tableActive.search( this.value ).draw();
})
```

or id you use the oldschool `dataTable()` initialisation bacause you need the jQuery instance :

```
var tableActive = $(<selector>).dataTable({ .. });

$('#search-users').on('keyup',function() {
  tableActive.api().search( this.value ).draw();
})
```

Only if you actually *want* **case sensitive** filtering you'll need :

```
var tableActive = $(<selector>).DataTable({
  caseInsensitive: false
});
```

Comment: i tried to but i got this notification-Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.